# Apache Too many open files (24)

Tags: php, linux, apache, session

Since there's many answers to this question "Too many open files (24)" and how to solve it just increasing number of allowed open files limit i have not found any suggestion how to check who is using these files.

I'm getting this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Unknown: open(/var/lib/php/session/sess_375048d5pfne5cu3v0l3sjji04, O_RDWR) failed: Too many open files (24)' in

Also I have restarted my apache process:

```
$ ps aux | grep apa
84:root      7528  0.0  0.1 102376  4908 ?        Ss   11:11   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
85:www-data  7531  0.0  0.0 101528  2952 ?        S    11:11   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
86:www-data  7532  0.0  0.1 1309308 7168 ?        Sl   11:11   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
87:www-data  7533  0.0  0.1 1309308 7312 ?        Sl   11:11   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
91:vagrant   7748  0.0  0.0   8860   648 pts/0    S+   11:20   0:00 grep --color=auto -in apa
```

Is there any tool to check who's using these files since my virtual box machine actually is sleeping by `htop`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into the directory `/var/lib/php`! You will find a lot of files starting with `sess_` there. These files contain the session data of your visitors.

How can you check, who is using these files:

```
lsof -n|grep -F /var/lib/php/sess_
```

will give you a process list, which *processes* are using them.

If you remove these files (`rm -vf /var/lib/php/sess_*`), all of your current visitors will lose their current session (they need to re-login into your site), but the problem will be solved.

A long-term solution would be to expire your sessions more often. In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes) you can find, how can you set up in your php to automatically remove expired session files. On my opinion, setting `session.cookie_lifetime` to around a half hour and `session.gc_maxlifetime` a little bit longer (f.e. 35 minutes) is okay.

If you have only a small site with a few visitors (at most some tens daily), it is far enough if you delete the old session files daily from crontab.

If you have a big site, or you want a super user-friendly (but not so secure) site, you need to be able to handle a *lot* of sessions. On my opinion, in this case it is better if you use some alternate php session solution with a database backend.

The command `find /var/lib/php -type f -name "sess_*" \! -ctime 1440|xargs -P 1 -n 50 rm -vf` will delete all files in this directory starting with `sess_` and older as a day.